# Doubts about creating an specific query

Tags: php, sql

Ok I have a database where i generate a ticket code everytime a users buy an item. With this code they have the oportunity to win a price

To win the price they have to go to a register form, where the code is ask.. thats where the data is really generated. I ask for name, mail address, and other non important stuff

This part is working nice and properly. but i need to create o new function to detect the best buyers. So when they enter the code to participate , i ask for their mail, i have noticed, they actually enters the same mail each time they register a code. So this is the best way i think to select my best clients, and the most interested on promotions also.

So I think the best is to build a query to search into the mail row .. inside users table, and look for coincidences, and then this query can drop me a list of the most "repited" mails in DSC order,

is this posible, can i build a query like this? how?

Ok , thansk for the comments (why the downvote??) anyway

The structure is

ID |  name | lastname | mail | phone | zipcode | birth |

And sorry at this moment i just CANT figure out a query thats why i ask. sorry for been a fool ,

Comment: What is your schema? Did you think of any queries? If you don't want this closed I suggest you add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to order by the number of times a certain element occurs in a table

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS top,mail,name lastname FROM users GROUP BY mail ORDER BY top DESC

This works because of [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///group-by-functions.html)

**COUNT**

Picks the number of rows in the individual elements of the group by (so suppose you ran count without a group by it would just return number of rows in the table)

**GROUP BY**

Groups the rows by common elements from the column(s) specified by the group by.

So in the above case it will group all the mails together and count the rows in each group.

Comment: everything works perfect, just one question, i have the list now, but i dont know how to echo the "count" for each user (of how many times that email was entered) thanks but works lovely.

Comment: Count is stored as the column top. Just access it the way you would access a normal column and ask for top

Comment: thanks :D really apreciate, so if i use another query in the same page... Can i select * from users, and order using top?

Answer (score 2):

Just count by row and group by email:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS top_buyers, mail FROM users GROUP BY mail ORDER BY top_buyers DESC
```

Comment: In your query how can i select all data from each top buyer to print, select * ?

Comment: You can `SELECT COUNT(*) AS top_buyers, * FROM users`

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work.

```
select email, count(*) as num_entries from emails group by email order by num_entries desc;
```

Comment: can i select all * to print all the respective data from each winner?

Comment: you could follow up with `select * from emails where email='somematchingemail';` but with a grouped result the detail is not available;

Comment: Ok so wich variables can i echo?? just the mail?

Comment: with this query yes... this was designed to determine who your top buyers are... if there is more information that you need then the query could be adapted.